# Convert format 0d 22h 41min to a time in any format using a formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column of data that I want to sort based on the time from earliest to latest.

The format of the data is presented as:

0d 22h 41min,

0d 2h 3min

Etc.

What's the best way to do this? I'm assuming extract the numbers, 0, 22, and 41, and then use a calculation to turn it into minutes which will then allow me to reorder it?

Please advise best way, and also formula if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming days hours and minutes are always present then with data in A2 try this formula in B2 to convert to a time value:

`=SUM(MID(0&A2,FIND({"d","h","m"},0&A2)-2,2)/{1,24,1440})`

Custom format B2 as `[h]:mm` to show total hours and minutes......and you can then sort both columns using B as the "key"

That will cope with values as large as 99 days - for higher numbers of days try this version

`=LEFT(A2,FIND("d",A2)-1)+SUM(MID(A2,FIND({"h","m"},A2)-2,2)/{24,1440})`

Comment: That's pretty impressive and works - thanks, however, I do need to go above 99 days ... can you tweak your formula or give me some guidance? With regards

Comment: I added a revised version that will work for any number of days

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect - appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways, but some simple string manipulation and concatenation can be used in a formula:

Assuming

```
A1 = 0d 22h 41min
A2 = 0d 2h 3min
```

First you must extract the hh and the mm using the MID() function

You can do this by using the FIND() function to search for where a 'd', 'h' and 'm' occurs to extract the numbers between them.

Finally you simply concatenate the 22:41 together using ":"

For A1 (put in another column i.e B1):

```
=MID(A1, FIND( "d", A1) + 2, SUM( FIND( {"d","h"}, A1) * {-1,1}) - 2 )&":"&IF(LEN(MID(A1, FIND( "h", A1) + 2, SUM( FIND( {"h","m"}, A1) * {-1,1}) - 2))=2,MID(A1, FIND( "h", A1) + 2, SUM( FIND( {"h","m"}, A1) * {-1,1}) - 2 ),"0"&MID(A1, FIND( "h", A1) + 2, SUM( FIND( {"h","m"}, A1) * {-1,1}) - 2 ))
```

The result should be

```
A1 = 0d 22h 41min
A2 = 0d 2h 3min

B1 = 22:41
B2 = 2:03
```

It should be noted that if a "3min" occurs, we use the LEN() function to see if the minute value is 1 character or 2 characters long. If it is 2 characters (i.e 41) leave it as is. If it is 1 character (i.e 3) then put a 0 infront of it to get 03.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data in column A, cells A1, A2 etc, you can use following formulas to extract days, hours and minutes, and then add everything up:

First, extract days into cell B1:

> =LEFT(A1, FIND("d",A1) - 1)

Now, hours into C1:

> =MID(A1, FIND("d", A1)+2, FIND("h", A1)-FIND("d", A1)-2)

And minutes into D1:

> =MID(A1, FIND("h", A1) + 1, FIND("min",A1)-FIND("h", A1)-1)

Put sum of days into E1:

> =B1*24*60 +C1*24 +D1

And now sort on column E.

Another possibility is to find and replace data using regular expression:

find:

> ([0-9]{1,2})d ([0-9]{1,2})h ([0-9]{1,2})min

replace:

> =\1*24*60+\2*24+\3

[This page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx#_Toc286834991) describes replace behavior on example of dates manipulation.